# Saving `h2o_model.accuracy` printed output to a file

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, h2o

`h2o_model.accuracy` prints model validation data when executed in a Jupyter Notebook cell (which is desirable, despite the function name). How to save this whole validation output (entire notebook cell contents) to a file? Please test before suggesting redirections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd be careful using `%%capture`, it doesn't capture html content (tables) in the `stdout`.

The `redirect_stdout` works flawlessly when used from python CLI/script. IPython/Jupyter might cause issues with tables as they are `display`ed not `print`ed. Note that you should not use `.readlines()` to get the results from `StringIO` - use `.getvalue()`.

You can use `h2o_model.save_model_details(path)` to persist information about the model to a json file (which might serve you better in a long run but it's not really human readable).

If you really want to have the output that looks like what would you get from a Jupyter notebook, you can use the following hack:

- create a template jupyter notebook that contains:

```py
import os
import h2o
h2o.connect(verbose=False)
h2o.get_model(os.environ["H2O_MODEL"])
```

- and in your original notebook add

```sh
!H2O_MODEL={h2o_model.key} jupyter nbconvert --to html --execute template.ipynb --output={h2o_model.key}_results.html
```

You can also create a template for the `nbconvert` to hide the code cells.

Comment: It worked nicely, after only a few adjustments (like loading model file from a shared folder and passing h2o container url and credentials via other env vars). I did manage to automate the creation of `template.ipynb` as well (using this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45672031/9962007).

Answer (score 1):

You should call `h2o_model.accuracy()` (note the parentheses). The reason the whole model gets printed is non-idiomatic implementation of `__repl__` in h2o models which prints rather then returning a string (there's a JIRA to fix that).

If you encounter some other situation where you would like to save printed output of some command, you can use `redirect_stdout`[1] to capture it (assuming you have python 3.4+).

[1] https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout

Comment: Thank you, but I do want the whole validation output, not just accuracy (to save as a text file to MLflow). No redirections I tried worked... if you managed to hack it, do post it though.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so only the `h2o_model.accuracy` output cannot be captured, while `xgb_model.cross_validation_metrics_summary` or even `h2o_model` alone can - e.g. like that:

```
%%capture captured_output

# print model validation 
# data to `captured_output`
xgb_model
```

In another notebook cell:

```
# print(captured_output.stdout.replace("\n\n","\n"))

with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    f.write((captured_output.stdout.replace("\n\n","\n")))
```